lookup and sum then trasnpose patterned with dates
Can anyone help me in doing this with Formula I don't want to use VBA.
so

do a lookup (if you can use Filter formula) with ‘code’ trigger, to produce ‘Qty’ and ‘Date’
after that, the lookup result data, is summed and right-transposed but both are patterned (the result is as shown below)

I have got the formula but it is very long and makes my excel very heavy, because my data consists of thousands of rows, and I want a dynamicarray result row by row
The current formula:
=LET(trigger,U2,unit,L2,triggerdel,'Delivery Report'!AA:AA,delr,HSTACK('Delivery Report'!A:A,'Delivery Report'!N:O),data,FILTER(delr,triggerdel=trigger),date,UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(data,1)),LET(pcs,INDEX(data,,2),kgs,INDEX(data,,3),deldat,INDEX(data,,1),kotak,VSTACK(TRANSPOSE(date),TRANSPOSE(MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(deldat)=date),pcs))),TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("|",,CONCATENATE(CHOOSEROWS(kotak,1),"|"&CHOOSEROWS(kotak,2))),"|")))
but very long and heavy. That formula only produces 1 row, so I copied it down to row 1000+.




No
Nama
Code
Qty
Date




1
a
1
10
7-Jan


2
a
1
15
7-Jan


3
a
1
20
10-Jan


4
a
1
30
10-Jan


5
b
2
40
16-Jan


6
b
2
50
28-Jan


7
b
2
60
28-Jan






No
Nama
Code
Qty 1
Date 1
Qty 2
Date 2
**ignore the column header, it's manually written




1
a
1
25
7-Jan
50
10-Jan



2
b
2
40
16-Jan
110
28-Jan





I put your data in range AI4:AJ10

=LET(
    namas, AI4:AI10,
    codes, AJ4:AJ10,
    qtys, AK4:AK10,
    dates, AL4:AL10,
    unique_namas_and_codes, UNIQUE(HSTACK(namas, codes), FALSE, FALSE),
    sorted_dates, SORT(UNIQUE(dates, FALSE, FALSE)),
    numRows, ROWS(unique_namas_and_codes),
    numDates, ROWS(sorted_dates),
    qtys_by_date, MAKEARRAY(
        numRows,
        numDates,
        LAMBDA(r, c,
            LET(
                nama, INDEX(unique_namas_and_codes, r, 1),
                code, INDEX(unique_namas_and_codes, r, 2),
                d, INDEX(sorted_dates, c, 1),
                filtered, FILTER(qtys, (namas = nama) * (codes = code) * (dates = d), 0),
                SUM(filtered)
            )
        )
    ),
    VSTACK(HSTACK("Nama", "Code", TOROW(sorted_dates)), HSTACK(unique_namas_and_codes, qtys_by_date))
)

If you want to get your results in one formula, you need to use MAKEARRAY or REDUCE.
The core function in MAKEARRAY lambda is FILTER(qtys, (namas = nama) * (codes = code) * (dates = d), 0), it filtered out qtys for each namas, codes and dates, and then sum them.
If you want your columns to be arranged in "Qty1", "Date1", "Qty2", "Date2", then you might need nested REDUCE. that will make the formula way more complicated. so I chose the easier layout: columns = dates, rows = aggregated quantities.

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac), and will create the output in the layout you specify, along with the Column Headers as needed:
To use Power Query

Select some cell in your Data Table
Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range or from within sheet
When the PQ Editor opens: Home => Advanced Editor
Make note of the Table Name in Line 2
Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
Read the comments and explore the Applied Steps to understand the algorithm

You will have to "refresh" the query whenever you update the table
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source table name
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="myTable"]}[Content],

//PQ has defined data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"No", Int64.Type}, {"Nama", type text}, {"Code", Int64.Type}, {"Qty", Int64.Type}, {"Date", type date}}),

//Group by {Code, Nama, Date} and compute Sum of Qty
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Code", "Nama", "Date"}, {
        {"Qty", each List.Sum([Qty]), type nullable number}}),

//Group by {Code, Name}  and create the new columns
    #"Grouped Rows1" = Table.Group(#"Grouped Rows", {"Code", "Nama"}, {
        {"Dates", (t)=>
            let 
                rws = Table.RowCount(t),
                rwsText =List.Transform(List.Numbers(1,rws),each Text.From(_)),
                
             //Names of date and qty columns   
                dtCols = List.Transform(List.Zip({List.Repeat({"Date"},rws),rwsText}),each Text.Combine(_," ")),
                qtyCols = List.Transform(List.Zip({List.Repeat({"Qty"},rws),rwsText}),each Text.Combine(_," ")),

             //Create the records
                dtRecs = Record.FromList(t[Date],dtCols),
                qtyRecs = Record.FromList(t[Qty],qtyCols),
                combineRecs = dtRecs & qtyRecs,

                recOrder = List.Combine(List.Zip({qtyCols,dtCols})),
                #"Reorder Fields" = Record.ReorderFields(combineRecs,recOrder)

             in 
                #"Reorder Fields"}}),

    colNames =
        Record.FieldNames(
            List.Select(#"Grouped Rows1"[Dates], (li)=> 
                Record.FieldCount(li)=
                    List.Max(
                        List.Transform(
                            #"Grouped Rows1"[Dates],each Record.FieldCount(_)))){0}),
    
    colTypes = List.Zip({List.Alternate(colNames,1,1,0),List.Repeat({type date}, List.Count(colNames) / 2)})
                & List.Zip({List.Alternate(colNames,1,1,1),List.Repeat({Int64.Type}, List.Count(colNames) / 2)}),
    
    #"Expand Grouped Rows1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Grouped Rows1","Dates",colNames),
    #"Set Types" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expand Grouped Rows1",colTypes)
    
in
    #"Set Types"



Can make it a bit shorter by using Groupby as below but still quite long:
=LET(data,A2:E8,
g,GROUPBY(CHOOSECOLS(data,{2,3,5}),CHOOSECOLS(data,4),SUM,0,0),
u,UNIQUE(TAKE(g,,2)),
rows,ROWS(u),
colsPerRow,BYROW(u,LAMBDA(r,SUM(--(TAKE(g,,1)=r))))*2,
cols,MAX(colsPerRow),
HSTACK(SEQUENCE(rows),u,MAKEARRAY(rows,cols,LAMBDA(r,c,IF(c>INDEX(colsPerRow,r),"",
   LET(x,XMATCH(INDEX(u,r,1),TAKE(g,,1))+(c-1)/2,IF(ISODD(c),INDEX(g,x,4),TEXT(INDEX(g,x,3),"dd-mmm"))))))))



This formula works in my Excel for the web sheet.
=LET(rng,
B2:E8,
unique_nama_code_date,
UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(rng,1,2,4)),
sum_qty,
HSTACK(
unique_nama_code_date,
MAP(INDEX(unique_nama_code_date,,1),
INDEX(unique_nama_code_date,,2),
INDEX(unique_nama_code_date,,3),
LAMBDA(a,b,c,
SUMIFS(INDEX(rng,,3),INDEX(rng,,1),a,INDEX(rng,,2),b,INDEX(rng,,4),c)))),
unique_nama_code,
UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(sum_qty,1)&"|"&CHOOSECOLS(sum_qty,2)),
HSTACK(
SEQUENCE(ROWS(UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(rng,1,2)))),
UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(rng,1,2)),
IFNA(DROP(REDUCE("",unique_nama_code,LAMBDA(u,v,
VSTACK(u,TOROW(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(sum_qty,3,4),
CHOOSECOLS(sum_qty,1)&"|"&CHOOSECOLS(sum_qty,2)=v))))),1),"")))


